# What does Yoda wear around his neck?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

I visited a [Star-Wars exposition](https://thesffblog.com/2012/08/star-wars-identities-the-exhibition/) this summer and I noticed that Yoda was wearing something strange around his neck:

[image: Yoda]

This looks like a small book, what is it?

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn we discussed this when I uploaded my pictures from the exhibition. But maybe it was in the chat room. At least, I don't find a dupe. However, I see they improved the lighting in that section since I was there.

Comment: @bitmask Yeah, it was in the chat room. Since I find the information interesting, and we eliminated the GR rule, I decided to post the questions and the answer.

Comment: I don't think the GR would have applied anyway.

Comment: Well, the old 80's action figure had a snake around his neck. Does that count?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a [blissl](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Blissl), a musical instrument similar to a pan flute.

This information was revelled the February 28, 2002 on *starwars.com*'s *Ask the Lucasfilm Jedi Council*. The original page is unavailable, but it's [archived here](http://web.archive.org/web/20050204102838/http://www.starwars.com/community/askjc/jocasta/askjc20020228.html) :

> **Q :** What is that thing around Yoda's neck?
>
> **A :** Yoda wears a blissl around his neck, which is similar to a pan flute.

Comment: http://misc.thefullwiki.org/Blissl_tuner mentions that a tuner exists for them, and that they were used on Tattoine.  Wonder where he got the blissl, one does.

Comment: Unsurprising. [He’s a musical guy.](https://youtu.be/U9t-slLl30E)